# Relative Velocities and Conservation of Kinetic Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

An object of mass m moves with velocity $v$ towards a stationary object of same mass. Impact is an elastic collision.

$v_1$ is the velocity after impact of the mass originally moving

$v_2$ is the velocity after impact of the mass originally stationary

Elastic collision means K.E. is conserved, so:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}m(v_1)^2+\frac{1}{2}m(v_2)^2$$
Thus,
$$v^2=(v_1)^2+(v_2)^2$$

However, using relative velocities:

$$-v=(v_1)-(v_2)$$

Squaring both sides gives a different value for $v^2$. Instead of $v^2=v_1^2+v_2^2$, $v^2=v_1^2-2v_1v_2+v_2^2$. How come?

Comment: What is the velocity of the mass originally moving *after* the collision?

Comment: The relative velocities equation comes from both energy conservation and momentum conservation. So why should squaring the last get the first velocity equation?

Comment: Please explain how u came up the relative velocitiess

Comment: You are just algebraically multiplying vectors. It must be as $\mathrm{2v_1 v_2 cos({\theta)}}$

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason squaring equation (2) should give equation (1), because they are independent equations. You can use this fact to solve for $v_1$ and $v_2$; if this weren't so then using both conservation of energy and momentum would be rather useless.